# update value of virtual attribute in view is not updating model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, virtual-attribute

I'm updating the value of a virtual attribute in my view but this is not being reflected in the model instance.

For example:

MyModel.erb

```
attr_accessor_with_default :hello_world, false
```

View.html.erb

```
<%= @mymodel.hello_world %><br/>
<% 
    if ( @mymodel.hello_world == false )
        @mymodel.hello_world = true
    end
%>
<%= @mymodel.hello_world %>
```

The view outputs:

```
false
true
```

However, when I reload the page the same output is shown, when it should be:

```
true
true
```

I am seeing the above behaviour in an edit form.  When I submit the form (with validation errors) it reloads (displaying errors) but the value for hello_world is not being updated.

Do you have any suggestions?
**What should I do to get the desired behaviour?**

Comment: This looks correct to me. Why do you expect the reloaded page to display true, true. The reload is a completely new request with a completely new instance of @mymodel

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your comment.  How would you suggest I get the behaviour that I require?  Use the session?

Comment: If you wish to maintain state between requests and you do not wish to persist the data to some form of permanent storage then the session is the way to go.

Comment: I've updated my approach to use a session-based variable and it works well - thanks.  If you wish to answer the question I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is working as expected. The hello_world virtual attribute is being initialized as false and then set to true. The problem is your expectation of what will happen  when you refresh the page.

The refreshed page is seen as a totally new request to rails with it's own (new) copy of @mymodel. This is why your results are the same when the refresh is done as the old value of @mymodel.hello_world is lost when the new instance is created.

If you wish to avoid this you will need some mechanism to persist the value between requests. This can either be some form of persistent storage such as a database or you can use the standard mechanism for persisting temporary values between requests, namely the session.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual attributes are not persistent between requests since they are just stored in the @mymodel instance and not in a session or database. Every time you refresh the page, a new instance of @mymodel is created and doesn't know anything about the virtual attributes previously assigned to it.

If it's an attribute that you want to save, you should store it in the database like a regular model attribute.